# There is Any response during getting data from SQLite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, contextmenu

First, my situation has no error but any response when I touch the context menu 'delete'. It seem to computer remain can't readable state.

getAmount calss of DBHelper.java

```
public int getAmount(Integer id){
    int amount = 0;
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT id, amount FROM uselist WHERE id="+id,null);
    amount=res.getInt(res.getColumnIndex(USELIST_COLUMN_AMOUNT));
    return amount;
}
```

Code above getAmount have used

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    int itemId = item.getItemId();
    switch (itemId){
        case R.id.context_item1 :
            Toast.makeText(this,"edit",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.context_item2 :
            int amt=-mydb.getAmount(position);
            Toast.makeText(this,"delete",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mydb.deleteUseList(position);
            mydb.update("UPDATE uselist SET id = (id-1) WHERE id >"+ position+";");
            mydb.update("UPATE uselist SET balance = (balance+"+amt+") WHERE id>"+position+";");
            histories.clear(); //
            finish();
            startActivity(getIntent());
            return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

I guess something wrong in 'int amt=-mydb.getAmount(position);'code or getAmount class since the delete Toast not appear.

Comment: Why have you used `-mydb` instead of `mydb' ??

Comment: @Jas remove then remain same problem. The minus sign is needed for my purpose.

Comment: @Jiwon need some clarity on your question.

Comment: Try debugging and check whether you are getting the value in variable amt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public int getAmount(Integer id){
    int amount = 0;
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT id, amount FROM uselist WHERE id="+id,null);

            // looping through all rows and setting value to variable
            if (res.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    amount=res.getInt(res.getColumnIndex(USELIST_COLUMN_AMOUNT));
                } while (res.moveToNext());
            }

     return amount;
   }
```

Comment: Oh, app proceeded, but now app stop somewhere after 'mydb.update("UPDATE uselist SET id = (id-1) WHERE id >"+ position+";");'

And I can't understand why my app proceeded by your trial.

Comment: Is your app crashing??

Comment: Thank you, I corrected UPATE to UPDATE. App is working well. Your trial made my app work but, not desired function. I want your explain how did you made my app work. What was the problem in my app??

Comment: Accept my answer if it helped you :)

Comment: You have to loop through your cursor to retrieve values and you missed to do that. That was your problem.